# Aparecer um modal bootstrap antes do HTML

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma página do qual após 03 tentativas o acesso a página é bloqueada. Porém gostaria que caso a página estiver bloqueada, ao tentar acessar, aparecer um modal bootstrap com uma mensagem:

> Página bloqueada. Favor entrar em contato com o administrador para
>   solicitar o desbloqueio.

E que esse modal fosse ativado dentro dessa condição em PHP:

```
if($visualizarVerificar->Bloqueado == "S"){
        // Entraria aqui a ativação do modal Boostrap
        echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
        exit;
}
```

Isso é possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Biblioteca**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Modal HTML**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Página bloqueada</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Favor entrar em contato com o administrador para solicitar o desbloqueio.</p>
                <p class="text-warning"><small>contato</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
if($visualizarVerificar->Bloqueado == "S"){
    echo "<script>
        $(\"#myModal\").modal('show');
    </script>"; 

    exit();
}
```

> O script depois do Modal HTML

[**Teste - Pagina Bloqueada**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/pagina-bloqueada.php)